# IF statement to ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula in D3 that look like this:

```
=IF(B3="","",B3-B2)
```

How do I fill the whole column D (from D3) with that formula using ArrayFormula?

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="",,B3:B-ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(B2:B,ROWS(B3:B),1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B501="","",B2:B500-B3:B501))`

Comment: Thanks! Will this only apply the formula to the first 500 rows?